# Walker or wp_get_nav_menu_items VS jQuery

Tags: menus, jquery, walker

**Self wondering question**

I have a menu configuration like so (as an example) :

```
<nav class="nav-wrapper">
    <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a href="#0">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">About</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#0" class="subnav-trigger"><span>Links</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0">Lk 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0">Lk2 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0">Lk 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0" class="holder">holder</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul> <!-- .main-nav -->
</nav> <!-- .nav-wrapper -->
```

As you can see, only **any** `<li>` that has children will get a particular output.
Using `wp_nav-menu` :

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location' => 'menu',
    'container' => 'nav',
    'container_class' => 'nav-wrapper',
    'menu_class' => 'main-nav',
    'depth' => 2
));
```

We can get each of the main `menu-item`, but to output the `<li>` that has children, we would have to write a custom `Walker` or use the `wp_get_nav_menu_items` function.

I couldn't get the output as intended...
**But any function will not be less than 3 lines of code** while in jQuery I just did it **with 2 lines** :

```
$('ul li:has(ul) > a').addClass('subnav-trigger').wrapInner('<span/>');
$('ul li ul').prepend('<li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Menu</a></li>').append('<li><a href="#0" class="holder">holder</a></li>');
```

**My self question and for others** :
Should I make it work with a custom `Walker` or a WP function ?!
If yes, why lose time and bytes while in jQuery it's only 2 lines of code ?!

Thanks in advance for all of your response(s).
Of course, I'll be more than grateful to see the `Walker` or any other function for this `<li>` that have children, but the question is more important for me to understand the purpose if I really should go here the WP way instead of the jQuery way.
Thanks again, SYA :)

Answer (score 0):

As you know, walker is server side method while jQuery is client side method. You need to choose what will be the best in any situation.
If you don't use a dedicated Walker for each menu, default WordPress Walker will run so why don't use your own and adapt it via jQuery for the different support target ?

Comment: Hello, first of all thanks a lot for responding.  
I only have this menu and it has a 7 KB JavaScript file to handle different screen/window size. Adding this 2 lines of code makes perfect sense to me rather than requesting a server side function of at least 10 lines to do the work. And this is why I'm wondering if it's not more logical to go the jQuery way...

Comment: jQuery or not, you'll need a server side way with wp_nav_menu to build the menu that jQuery will modify

Comment: Hello again, I think you miss understood my question. The menu is of course builded by wp_nav_menu as you can see above. My question is more like : why (or should I) use a custom Walker to modify the menu's output if jQuery does it with only 2 lines?

Comment: I totally understand  I just talk about the process, i though it was an evidence after : the server side method is in fact mandatory when wp_nav_menu runs so jQuery is not very usefull except if you need something to change DOM without refresh page on user action.